# Flask non-template HTML files included by Jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

In my Flask application, I have one html file that holds some html and some js that semantically belongs together and cannot be used separately in a sensible way. I include this file in 2 of my html templates by using Jinja's `{%include ... %}`.

Now my first approach was to put this file in my templates folder. However, I never call `render_template` on this file, so it seems unapt to store it in that directory.

Another approach would be to put it into the static folder, since its content is indeed static. But then I don't know how to tell Jinja to look for it in a different directory, since all the files using Jinja are in the templates folder.

Is there a way to accomplish this with Jinja, or is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: Let's say you could indeed make it so that jinja pulls it from your statics folder. Still, jinja would render the file on `%include`, so you'd have to protect your file contents from accidentally being parsed as jinja syntax (tags etc.). But then the file wouldn't be a 'static' by definition anymore, since contents could change at render-time. And that's more the behavior of a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-thinking this. If it's included by Jinja, then it's a template file and belongs in the templates directory.

Comment: OK thank you. I probably thought the templates directory holds templates in the Flask sense (aka called `render_template` in the Flask application). But if one thinks about it in a way where it holds templates in the Jinja sense, it makes sense.